# Post-receive hook that auto deploy newly pushed data?

Tags: git, auto-update, githooks

I'm looking to implement a post-receive script that would deploy my newly pushed data to a local folder.

Using Linux/bash I already done something equivalent, but I use `git pull`, and I often have conflicts when the local folder have some changes regarding the pull (the website is running).

I don't know if the best way is to keep the pull, or do a reset or something else, better, cleaner?

By the way, would it be possible to automatically deploy the newly pushed data only if I indicate it, without having to make a branche/tag everytime? I'm a newbie with git and I don't know if this is possible.

The reason I'd like this is since a push automatically update the website, I sometime want to save the changes but not everything is fully working.

Thank you really much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For conflicts in **git pull**, go use **.gitignore**.
2. For controllable deployment, you can put some magic word in your committing log and check that word in your **post-receive**.

Comment: By the way, do you know if git pull return a status != 0 in case of error (like in case of conflicts ?)

Comment: What do you mean? Something like **git pull || exit** ?

Comment: It supposed to work, and you can find lots of similar commands in **post-receive** example scripts on Internet.